# Infinite-dimensional Banach has proper dense subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Show that every (separable) infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ contains a proper vector subspace $Y$ with $cl (Y)$ = $X$

This is Exercise 1 (f) p.245 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387295704).

Assuming $X$ is separable, there is an increasing sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces $G_n$ such that $G:=\bigcup_n G_n$ is dense in $E$. The vector subspace $span(G)$ is dense as well.
Since $X$ has infinite dimension, each $G_n$ is closed and has empty interior. By Baire's theorem, $G$ has empty interior. However this does not imply that $span(G)\neq X$.

Can this line of thought lead to a solution ? Completely different solutions are fine.
I'm also interested in a proof for the case where $X$ is not separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spaces $G_n$ are non decreasing so $G$ is already a dense vector subspace. You may then apply Baire's category theorem to conclude that $G$ has empty interior.

In general when $X$ is an infinite dimensional real normed vector space it has a dense hyperplane. You can show it in three steps:

- For all $\varphi : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ linear, either $N(\varphi) = \operatorname{Ker} \varphi $ is closed; either it is dense.
- For all $\varphi : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ linear, $\varphi$ is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed.
- There exists a linear non continuous form on $X$.

Comment: Existence of dense hyperplane cannot be proved in ZF.  Its usual proof uses Hahn-Banach.  Can the question of the OP be done without using HB?  For an explicitly defined Banach space, is there an explicitly defined proper dense linear subspace?

Comment: @GEdgar This is a good remark, could you specify what means "explicitly"? Also I guess that your second questions means : the mapping "Banach space" to "discontinuous linear form" is independent of the axiom of the choice, right?

Comment: Example.  For the Banach space $l^1$, consider the linear subspace of sequences with finite support.  This is dense, and we did not use HB.  To find a dense **hyperplane** of $l^1$ we do need HB, and such hyperplane is not "explicitly defined".  So the question of dense subspace should be easier than the question of dense hyperplane.  True, I didn't say what I mean by "explicitly defined".  How about asking for a Borel set, say.

Comment: I am sorry I understand what it means in practice but in theory I don't know what is "explicit". Also I was not aware that it is not possible to find a dense hyperplane in $\ell^1$ without Hahn Banach (and I barely don't understand what does it mean), could you give me a reference?

Comment: @blamethelag: This question was recently cited (in a comment to a recently asked question) and, as I was looking over the comments posted here, I saw your comment. In the event that you have not found what you are looking for regarding "explicit" and the Hahn Banach theorem, see [**Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations**](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/ccc/) by Eric Schechter (1996; CD ROM version 1999), which has extensive discussions of these issues.